# Change base background in Compose

Tags: android, kotlin

I have an application that consists of a login with its registration, and then the rest of the screens. Normally with XML what I used to do was to have two activities (or 3 if I had splash) with their respective fragments.

One with the login and registration where they might share the same base background placed in the activity and then I had another activity that contained everything related to the dashboard of the application and the rest of the screens.

The purpose of Compose, or at least that's what I understood, is to have a main activity and not to have fragments, since all the screens can be assembled in composable functions.

So, after all this, how can I mimic the same XML scenario in Compose without using more than one activity? Currently I have something like this:

```kotlin
@Composable
fun LoginScreen(navController: NavController) {
    Box(
        modifier = Modifier.fillMaxSize(),
        contentAlignment = Alignment.BottomCenter
    ) {
        Image(
            painter = painterResource(id = com.isaacdelosreyes.firebaselogincompose.R.drawable.login_background),
            contentDescription = "Background del login",
            contentScale = ContentScale.Crop,
            modifier = Modifier.fillMaxSize()
        )
        ConstraintLayout() {

            val surface = createRef()

            Surface(
                Modifier
                    .fillMaxWidth()
                    .height(370.dp)
                    .clip(RoundedCornerShape(topStartPercent = 8, topEndPercent = 8))
                    .constrainAs(surface) {
                        bottom.linkTo(parent.bottom)
                    },
                color = Color.White
            ) {
                Column(
                    Modifier.fillMaxSize(),
                    verticalArrangement = Arrangement.Center
                ) {
                    Text(
                        text = "Iniciar sesión", style = TextStyle(
                            fontSize = 20.sp,
                            fontWeight = FontWeight.Bold
                        ), modifier = Modifier.padding(start = 30.dp, top = 20.dp)
                    )
                    LoginInput(textLabel = "Usuario", Icons.Default.Email, false)
                    LoginInput(textLabel = "Contraseña", Icons.Rounded.Lock, true)
                    LoginButton(
                        buttonTextValue = "Iniciar sesión",
                        paddingTopValue = 20.dp,
                        buttonColor = Green
                    ) {

                    }
                    LoginButton(
                        buttonTextValue = "Registrarme",
                        paddingTopValue = 5.dp,
                        buttonColor = Violet
                    ) {
                        navController.navigate("register")
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Where this would be my login screen, with its background, and then I have my registration screen:

```kotlin
@Composable
fun RegisterScreen(navController: NavController) {

    Box(
        modifier = Modifier.fillMaxSize(),
        contentAlignment = Alignment.BottomCenter
    ) {
        Image(
            painter = painterResource(id = R.drawable.login_background),
            contentDescription = "Background del login",
            contentScale = ContentScale.Crop,
            modifier = Modifier.fillMaxSize()
        )
        ConstraintLayout() {

            val surface = createRef()

            Surface(
                Modifier
                    .fillMaxWidth()
                    .height(600.dp)
                    .clip(RoundedCornerShape(topStartPercent = 8, topEndPercent = 8))
                    .constrainAs(surface) {
                        bottom.linkTo(parent.bottom)
                    },
                color = Color.White
            ) {
                Column(
                    Modifier.fillMaxSize(),
                    verticalArrangement = Arrangement.Center
                ) {
                    Text(
                        text = "Iniciar sesión", style = TextStyle(
                            fontSize = 20.sp,
                            fontWeight = FontWeight.Bold
                        ), modifier = Modifier.padding(start = 30.dp, top = 20.dp)
                    )
                    LoginInput(textLabel = "Usuario", Icons.Default.Email, false)
                    LoginInput(textLabel = "Contraseña", Icons.Rounded.Lock, true)

                    LoginButton(
                        buttonTextValue = "Registrarme",
                        paddingTopValue = 5.dp,
                        buttonColor = Violet
                    ) {
                        navController.navigate("register")
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

I could move the Image component that contains the background to the main activity because this way I don't repeat it in both, but if I always use this activity and I create what would be the dashboard where I want it not to have this background, what approach can I give it?